# Unix - need to remove line break from record spanning multiple lines

Tags: filesystems

I have a file as below

```
"IN001~24Apr16~Hi,
what a way?
oh no!~
not here~"
"IN003~29Apr16~
what a way?
~oh no!
say again.
not again~"
```

and I want the output in below format

```
"IN001~24Apr16~Hi,what a way?oh no!~not here~"
"IN003~29Apr16~what a way?~oh no!say again.not again~"
```

Any solution using awk or sed is much appreciated.

Comment: Your input and output looks similar, can you format it correctly and paste at least two lines for input ...

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ printf "%s",$0 }; /"$/ { print ""; };' inputfile
```

There shall be a newline in the output only if the input line ends with double quotes. Thus this `awk` code outputs all input lines without a newline. After that it checks whether the input line ends in a `"` and if so then a newline is output.

Comment: I really should ask you to qualify this with an explanation, but given my (first) comment underneath the question itself I'm going to OK this from the review queue _as is_.

Comment: @roaima You seem to imply that correctly working, unique code could be a "very low quality" answer; especially when the question is about a "solution" and not about an explanation. That would be a strange attitude.

Comment: Not at all. It was flagged in the LQ review queue, possibly because it was an unadorned single line of code. Sufficiently clever code that others could really benefit from an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -n -e '/^"/{h;n;}' -e H -e '/"$/{g;s/\n//g;p;}' file
"IN001~24Apr16~Hi,what a way?oh no!~not here~"
"IN003~29Apr16~what a way?~oh no!say again.not again~"
```

The `sed` command will...

- `/^"/{h;n;}`: copy all lines that start with `"` to the hold space (`h`), overwriting whatever was there, and immediately move on to the next line of input (`n`).
- `H`: Other lines are appended to the hold space.
- `/"$/{g;s/\n//g;p;}`: If a line ends with `"`, the hold space will be fetched (`g`) and newlines removed from it (these are added when appending lines to the hold space), and the resulting string is printed.

The command line can be compressed a bit:

```
$ sed -n '/^"/{h;n;};H;/"$/{g;s/\n//g;p;}' file
```